# Display VR 360 video from Android in Unity3d scene

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I created an Android app that displays a 360 video using `GLSurfaceView` class. And I'm using my custom mediaPlayer.
I want to display that video in Unity3d using an Android plugin so that I can play it in a VR headset (like Oculus quest, using the OVR sdk from Oculus). So my goal is when I click a button in my app, a Unity3d scene will be opened and displays that video in VR mode.

I know how to create an Android plugin, or calling a Unity scene inside Android, but I don't know how to display my 360 video from Android in Unity scene, should I pass the SurfaceView from android to Unity? and how ? (I'm open for other solutions)

Any hints will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding the video like how you add pictures. Just adding video as your asset and add it to the video player component.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOWFCYepN2c

If you couldn't, you can look out for other questions.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but as I said I'm using my own custom Android VideoPlayer to display the video.

Comment: Walid, yeah I notice; may I understand why you would want to use the Android VideoPlayer itself; when the Unity can run the video on its own function? Is it due to the resolution or the glitch?

Comment: because it's a streaming video and my custom player has some custom features. so I'm trying to figure out how to pass the textureView, or the player Object to Unity through the Plugin